# 3D javascript and html library for implementation of stick cricket kind of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, 3d

I want to create animation similar to stick cricket (http://www.sticksports.com/game/stick-cricket/2-player-1-keyboard/) in html + javascript. Can you please help what kind of library is available and can be used to achieve this. Can you please suggest some suitable libraries for my requirement. Any kind of help is hugely appreciated.

regards,
Subhankar

Comment: Please ask specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try tree.js

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

It uses WebGL and is the best 3D library at this very moment in my opinion.

Sincerly,

### Harmen Brinkman.

**Update**

I've checked out the link you posted, and i'm pretty sure that that is a flash game.
If so, then it's made in Adobe Flash, and pretty much not do-able in javascript and html only.